# Craft Licensing and Multiple Environments on Different Domains

Tags: craft3, license

It isn't currently clear how licences work with dev, staging and live environments or to be clearer how it works with different domains.

I have the following domains setup for different environments.

1. Local: name.test
2. Staging: sub.domain.co.uk
3. Preproduction: domain.co.uk
4. Production: livedomain.com

But this can't be configured on the Craft ID site as far as I'm aware? This also results in Licence Errors across staging and preproduction environments.

Is there a solution to what I'm describing?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [guide to how licensing is enforced](https://craftcms.com/guides/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain) :)